# Would a ring system for the Earth be a net benefit in terms of climate change? Is an artificial ring feasible?

Tags: design-alternative, engineering, climate, rings

The [greenhouse effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_effect) as I understand it is because sunlight hits the Earth, and is re-radiated as infrared heat, which is then trapped by greenhouse gasses in the atmosphere, like CO2 and Methane.

So wouldn't a ring system of low-albedo material intercept some percentage of that sunlight, re-radiate it in infrared, trapping it on the wrong side of the greenhouse gasses to contribute to warming?

Is this a reasonable approach to understanding the impact a ring system might have on the Earth?

If so, how feasible would creating an artificial ring system of dust be in order to block out, say 0.1% of sunlight hitting the Earth? Would material from the Moon be effective for this, or if we needed some more specific earthbound material (like... here's a legitimately good use for coal) could we feasibly launch enough material using [nuclear pulse propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)) or even more conventional means?

EDIT:

I'm really not interested in debating the pros and cons of an artificial ring vs an L1 sun-shield.  The latter would require decades of R&D and a vast manufacturing base devoted to it.  Considering that many leaders in the world and particular the US (one of the leading countries with any space infrastructure at all) seems to have an issue with even admitting climate change is a problem, I don't see an L1 sun-shield as politically viable, because by the time people are forced to admit we have a problem, it will probably be too late to practically implement such a thing with what's left of civilization.

A ring system on the other hand mostly just requires a vast lift capacity. Once Florida is underwater, I'm thinking the cost-benefit calculations for using nuclear pulse propulsion to launch material from Earth might change.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question relates to space exploration. It seems to be more about planetary and/or environmental sciences.

Comment: This question would probably better belong on WorldBuilding SE, but its not time to VTC yet.

Comment: Worldbuilding?  I'm absolutely not interested in the opinions of a bunch of writers as to the feasibility of this.  There's no "geoengineering" SE, and honestly I assumed the audience of this site would be in the best position to potentially refute the idea or explain why it's just not feasible.

Comment: It’s feasible. I don’t remember the exact numbers I worked up, but if I remember correctly you could put a climate-correcting amount of Mylar chaff into low Earth orbit with a few thousand Starship launches. It doesn’t matter much if the material is low albedo or high albedo; the important thing is getting a lot of area for the launched mass.

Comment: Mylar seems like it would be monstrously expensive not to mention bad for the environment in its own right.

Comment: This definitely isn't about Space Exploration - in fact it would probably sign the death knell for getting to space at all. Worldbuilding might be useful, as they do support "hard science"

Comment: Yes, it would be bad for satellites, wouldn't it ?  I think a dust area at the L1 lagrangian point would be more effective and then indeed moon material.

Comment: Sheets of graphene oxide would still be more effective since there is no rocket fuel on the Moon.

Comment: @Cornelis L1 isn't a stable point, and also is further away than the moon's orbit so the cloud would have to be colossal and constantly refreshed or otherwise maintained.  No we wouldn't be able to have satellites whose orbit intersected the ring, but given the choice between losing some satellites and becoming climate refugees I think most people would pick the former.

Comment: This article explores something similar: adding dust to the atmosphere to reflect sunlight.  It's certainly much more practical than putting anything in orbit. https://www.technologyreview.com/2013/02/08/84239/a-cheap-and-easy-plan-to-stop-global-warming/

Comment: Probably L1 is where Space Shades go because Rings need too much material - pi is not your friend. Astronomers won't be either. The question is too speculatively hypothetical for a definitive answer besides "No". If climate benefits are the point there are much better places to start.

Comment: You're right, a dust cloud wouldn't be stable at L1. But large sheets of graphene oxide would be only *nanometers* thick and could be held in place at the L1 point with solar cells and sails on the edges for respectively energy and steering.. It would have to be an intelligent system with sensoring too, but I think that would have to be no problem with sheets that could be km squares for one rocket payload.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. It may be on-topic, we've answered questions about terraforming before so why would this be different, but there's just too many questions in it.

Comment: I did a very simple calculation.  A 1000 km broad and 1 mm thick ring system around the Earth would need 4 million Starship launches with the material.